# Id format of Sinatra's form inputs

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb, nested-forms, parameters

We try to write nested forms in Sinatra. We can pass easly some values as model fields:

`id="user[name]"`

But what if we want to submit also related models? Assume we want to add a user and his 3 hobbies at the same time. How to pass them to params?

Answer (score 1):

Params get converted into a Hash based on the `name` attribute, not the `id` attribute.

To add more fields to this hash, add them to the form. The structure of these and how you process them depends completely on your implementation, but posting them is as simple as:

```
<form action="/route/to/post/to" method="POST">
  <input name="user[name]" id="user_name" type="text">
  <input name="user[hobbies][0][name]" type="text">
  <input name="user[hobbies][1][name]" type="text">
  <input name="user[hobbies][2][name]" type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

which will return:

```
{"user"=>{"name"=>"hiya", "hobbies"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"name"=>"2"}, "2"=>{"name"=>"3"}}}}
```